# vb.net check all row contain value

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset, odbc

I am a newbie in VB.Net.
Recently I want to check if the row contains a value or not, if contain, return true, if not, contain false.

Imagine this is my table call employee

```
DEPARTMENT  NAME
-------------------
   ABC      AAA
   CDE      BBB
   EFG      CCC
```

From what I know in PHP, we could use this to get all value from the row.

```
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) ){
        if($row['DEPARTMENT'] == "CDE"){
            echo "True";
        }
        else {
            echo "False";
        }
    }
```

And this is my code in VB.NET

```
 Dim da As Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
 Dim ds As DataSet
 Dim dt As DataTable
 da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM employee", Connection)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "employee")
    dt = ds.Tables("employee")
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        If (row("DEPARTMENT") = "ABC") Then
            MsgBox("True")
        Else
            MsgBox("False")
        End If
    Next
```

The Main problem is if I tried to get the first record, the statement if work. But when I tried to get record number 2, example `row("DEPARTMENT") = "CDE"` the result statement is always false, this should not correct because the row is contain "CDE". I tried to solve and googling it all day, but I can't find the way out

Comment: You need to start by accurately describing what you're trying to achieve.  Are you saying that you want to report whether or not each individual row contains a specific value in a specific column?  If that is correct then how does it make sense to have an `Exit Sub` in either branch of your `If` block?  If that is not what you want then please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of what you do want.  Are you saying that you just want to check whether there is any value?  If so, why are you testing for a specific value in your code?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, actually i just want to check if row department = abc, then they can read, update, delete and insert data from form, else the other department can only to read data

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  You already know how to check whether a row contains a particular value in a particular column because you're already doing it.  Enabling editing or not for a particular row based on the result is something else entirely and depends exactly how you're displaying the data to the user in the UI.

Comment: if there is more catagories on department, say that "XYZ" who can CRUD database, if i use that, XYZ only can read Data. of course i can use `If (row("DEPARTMENT") = "ABC") And (row("DEPARTMENT") = "XYZ") Then` , but i love to check it one by one with if function

Comment: So what you're saying is that you want to test whether the field contains any one of several specific values, correct?

Comment: yes of course, one of several spesific values, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is cross-reference the department with a collection of departments that have the privilege to CRUD a database?

The below can achieve this by creating a collection of privileged departments and checking that collection using LINQs`.Any()`.

P.S. This can be improved by making use of `String.Equals()` and `StringComparison` enumeration.

P.P.S Make use of `Using` statements when using `IDisposable` classes.

```
Dim departments As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) From {
        "ABC",
        "CDE"
    }

 Dim da As Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
 Dim ds As DataSet
 Dim dt As DataTable
 da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM employee", Connection)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "employee")
    dt = ds.Tables("employee")
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim department = row("DEPARTMENT").ToString()

        If departments.Any(Function(t) t.Equals(department, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) Then
            MsgBox("True")
        Else
            MsgBox("False")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i got an error Conversion from string "ABC" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.'

Comment: @Aria then you need to make boolean values List.